# Regular expression starting with http and ending with pdf?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have loaded the entire HTML of a page and want to retrieve all the URL's which start with http and end with pdf. I wrote the following which didn't work:

```
$html = file_get_contents( "http://www.example.com" );
preg_match( '/^http(pdf)$/', $html, $matches );
```

I'm pretty new to regex but from what I've learned `^` marks the beginning of a pattern and `$` marks the end. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regular expressions.

Comment: @hakre He seems to be looking for any link, that could be plain text link, so he's not looking to parse the HTML.

Comment: @Matthieu: In the code example, the first line is reading a full HTML source and the second line runs the regex over it. Doesn't that mean he wants to parse the HTML with a regex? How would you call that?

Comment: @hakre: How would you search for URLs in regular text? You are right about the do-not-parse-html-with-regex-thing, but the text-nodes could contain URLs, too. You cannot extract those information using a regular parser. His approach is totally reasonable.

Comment: @elusive: I was not aware that file_get_contents() is able to only extract textnodes from the HTML document.

Comment: @hakre: It isn't. But he is not trying to parse HTML with this regex. There is no case where the above construct would cause any trouble (as opposed to regex-html-parsing), so its fine.

Comment: @elusive: I wonder how you can say so. From the code example given in the question, he wants to parse plain text HTTP URIs from a HTML file. There is no iteration over the textnodes of the document nor is specified from which parts to extract the URLs.

Comment: @hakre: The OP says that he wants to test all URLs. He does not need to worry about HTML, since there are no HTML special characters in a URL whatsoever. It does not interfere with HTML markup.

Comment: @elusive: HTML can escape text sequences (which would interfere), but not enough with that, HTTP URLs have escape squences as well. The .pdf for example could be %-triplet encoded.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to match the characters in the middle of the URL:

```
/\bhttp[\w%+\/-]+?pdf\b/
```

- `\b` matches a word boundary
- `^` and `$` mark the beginning and end of the entire **string**.  You don't want them here.
- `[...]` matches any character in the brackets
- `\w` matches any word character
- `+` matches one or more of the previous match
- `?` makes the `+` lazy rather than greedy

Comment: Thanks. I understand it now. But what do you mean by "lazy vs greedy"?

Comment: Lazy means as few characters as possible.

Comment: not working for --> http://www.debrauw.com/wp-content/uploads/NEWS%2520-%2520NEWSLETTERS/Regulatory%2520and%2520Criminal%2520Enforcement%2520RCE/2013/RCE-Newsletter-8-February-2013.pdf

Answer (score 5):

`preg_match( '/http[^\s]+pdf/', $html, $matches );`

Matches `http` followed by not (`[^...]`) spaces (`\s`) one or more times (`+`) followed by `pdf`

Comment: I don't think my answer is worth downvoting, I can see no reason.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
preg_match( '/\bhttp\S*pdf\b/', $html, $matches );
```

You need to match the part between the `http` and the `pdf`, this is what `.*?` is doing.

`^` matches the start of the string and `$` the end, but this is not what you want, when you want to extract those links from a longer text.

`\b` is matching on word boundaries

**Update**

for completeness, the `.*?` would still match too much so exchanged with `\S*`

`\S` matches a non whitespace character

Comment: Why the `*?`? Isn't that 2 quantifiers after each other?

Comment: @ gnur the `?` makes the `*` ungreedy, otherwise the `.*` will match till the last pdf in the string

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
preg_match_all('/\bhttp\S*?pdf\b/', $html, $matches);
```

Note that you need to use the [`preg_match_all()`-function](http://php.net/preg_match_all) here, since you are trying to match more than one occurrence. `^` and `$` wont work, because they only apply to line or file boundaries (depending on the used modifiers).

Comment: I don't know why this got voted down, but i would love to hear the reason ;)

Answer (score 0):

`preg_match( '/^http.*pdf$/', $html, $matches );`

is better (working)